# AutoMapper Unity AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider Issue

Tags: c#, automapper, unity-container

I'm trying to register my AutoMapper (version 5.2.0) Profile class into my Unity container (Unity version 4.0.1), and it's giving me an exception:

Resolution of the dependency failed, type = IConsumer`1[Commands.INewUserEmailCommand]", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.  Exception is: **InvalidOperationException - The current type, AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?**

Here's the profile class:

```
public class AutoMapperBootstrap : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperBootstrap()
        {
            this.CreateMap<IUserEmailDTO, MergeUserEmailRequest>();
        }
    }
```

And here's the Unity registration snippet:

```
Profile typeMaps = new AutoMapperBootstrap();
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(typeMaps));
container.RegisterInstance<IMapper>(config.CreateMapper(), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Then I have constructors that depend on the IMapper instance being injected which apparently Unity knows nothing about or it needs some extra IConfigurationProvider instance?  What am I missing?  When my code needs to invoke a service that relies on IMapper, Unity is throwing the exception above.  Here's an example of a service that's using constructor injection trying to get an IMapper instance.

```
public class FooService : IFooService
{
  private readonly IMapper mapper;

  public Foo(IMapper mapper)
  {
    this.mapper = mapper;
  }
}
```

Comment: Should I just skip the container registration and use a static instance that has all the mappings?  I'm thinking of having a static constructor initialize the my profile so that it will always be available...

Answer (score 2):

@Andy, I think you just copy part of the error on your mapping, usually automapper gives you more details where it is failing and can give you a clue.

On the line below you are trying to register an instance of the IMapper class

```
container.RegisterInstance<IMapper>(config.CreateMapper(), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

If you take a look on how actually the CreateMapper works you will see that it uses an IConfigurationProvider, check the automapper original code below

```
public class MapperConfiguration : IConfigurationProvider
{
    .....

    public IMapper CreateMapper()
    {
       return (IMapper) new Mapper((IConfigurationProvider) this);
    }

    .....
}
```

When automapper is trying to create an instance of the `Mapper` is trying to resolve as well the parameter `IConfigurationProvider`. On this case you never injected that parameter. Resolution: Inject an instance of that parameter and that's all

Here I will save for you an example of how I am using it

```
class Helper
{
    public static MapperConfiguration InitializeAutoMapper()
    {
        MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new ProfileA());
            cfg.AddProfile(new ProfileB());
        });

        return config;
    }
}
```

Registering on your Unity where `container` is an instance of `IUnityContainer`

```
var mapperConfig = Helper.InitializeAutoMapper();
var mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
container.RegisterType<IMapper, Mapper>(new InjectionConstructor(mapperConfig));
container.RegisterInstance(mapper, Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
```